# Warning at closing the form, how to stop it

Tags: vb.net

I wish that user gets a warning when Close button is pressed.
I can put the warning message in _FormClosing event but I donot know how to stop closing if user choses to stop it.

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 4):

> To cancel the closure of a form, set
>   the Cancel property of the
>   FormClosingEventArgs passed to your
>   event handler to true.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs) _ 
     Handles Form1.FormClosing
   e.Cancel = true   'stop the form from closing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is correct, but you really should check `e.CloseReason` to verify that the close request is coming by specific action from the user. You don't want to prevent the form from closing when the Windows session is ending, for example.